# Select the time from the last register before another register in another column - Amazon redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am trying to select the time from the last register before another register in another column.

Here's the case:

I have some ids and two datetime columns that registers two different events

The column A can happen multiple times and the column B happens only once. Column A can happen before or after the event from B.

I want to select in another column the last time the column A happenned before column B. I am using AWS redshift. I've quite a success using last_value window function to get the last value from column A, but as it may occur after the column B register i am missing some entries. Here is an example:

| ID | event A | Event B | Last event A before event B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11:20 | 11:40 | 11:20 |
| 1 | 10:40 | 11:40 | 11:20 |
| 2 | 09:40 | 09:50 | 9:42 |
| 2 | 09:42 | 09:50 | 9:42 |
| 2 | 10:50 | 09:50 | 9:42 |
| 2 | 11:00 | 09:50 | 9:42 |

Comment: This can be done with window functions.  If you provide some sample input data the forum will provide you with some examples of how to do this.  (If you provide the data in "INSERT INTO <table> VALUES ..." it will be even faster)

Answer (score 0):

```
create table amish.window_test
(id int, time1 time, time2 time) 
insert into amish.window_test values 
(1, '11:20' ,'11:40'    ),
(1, '10:40' ,'11:40'    ),
(2, '09:40' ,'09:50'    ),
(2, '09:42' ,'09:50'    ),
(2, '10:50' ,'09:50'    ),
(2, '11:00' ,'09:50'    )

select id, time1,time2, max(case when time1 < time2 then time1 end) 
over (partition by id ) 
from amish.window_test
```